# Unicode symbols do not display on Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos, unicode

I am trying to display unicode symbols in a plot, but they do not display on Mac OS X 10.10. I am using cairo_pdf, since this solution worked well on a Fedora 20 OS, but not in this case. I checked I have the Cairo and Pango ports available in my Mac, so the issue might be related with the fonts not being correctly loaded in the R session. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
cairo_pdf(file='test.pdf')
pdfFonts("serif")
par(family="serif")
plot(1,1, main=expression("\u2600"))
dev.off()

sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3
```